# itext 7.1.2 percent table width

Tags: java, itext7

There is a iText 7.0.7 method of table that works:

```
Table table = new Table(new float [] {4,1,3,4,3,3,3,3,1});
table.setWidthPercent(100);
```

But in iText 7.1.2 this method is not found:

```
table.setWidthPercent(100);
```

They know what the new method is or where it has moved, please.

Answer (score 11):

Please try

```
table.setWidth(UnitValue.createPercentValue(100)):
```

In iText 7.1.x many dimension properties have been generalized to contain a `UnitValue` instance which can be either absolute (in points) or relative (in percent).

Comment: Thanks if it works!
One more query, the Color class does not exist in this version 7.1.2
You know where he has moved, or where I find more information. import com.itextpdf.kernel.color.Color;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.color.DeviceCmyk;

Comment: About a year a go the package `com.itextpdf.kernel.color` has been renamed to `com.itextpdf.kernel.colors`.